# JQuery Tabs - Styling issue on page content load

Tags: jquery, css, tabs

First tab on my page has a lot of content, including text and pictures.

This probably causes visual issue:

Once user loads the page, for a second, he will see regular html list instead of styled tabs with background.

Something like this:

- Tab One
- Tab Two
- Tab Three

All javascripts and css are loaded on top of the page in head section.

Does anyone know any solution to this issue?

Thanks in advance!

```
<script src="/js/jquery.ui/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/ui.tabs.css" type="text/css">

<script src="/js/jquery.ui/ui/ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.ui/ui/ui.tabs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```
        <div id="container-1">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#fragment-1"><span>Tab One</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#fragment-2"><span>Tab Two</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#fragment-3"><span>Tab Three</span></a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="fragment-1">

              !!!!!! A lot of html code and pictures here !!!!!!

            </div>
            <div id="fragment-2">
               some text 2
            </div>
            <div id="fragment-3">
               some text 3
            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: Paste the JS you use as well please.

Comment: Have you set in your css for your ul to have list-style-type : none;
 ?

Comment: if you have alot of html specially loaded with ajax you wont have much of a choice except to try the to style things similar to how it would look after the js has done its work. its always best to put the css first and after that link the scripts. whatever you do, don't hide things with css and make them appear with JS unless you are sure no one with any disability will view your page. or that you do not want to support people with no js

Comment: No XGreen, I didn't set list-style-type : none, since I need list items to look like tabs right away. I will use the idea to apply inline css for list items. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second the user sees a regular list is the amount of time jQuery and the tabs plugin need to initialize themselves. You will not be able to do much about that time.

However, you can style the `<li>` elements yourself in a way that makes them look good right from the start.

Open a browser window and wait until the tabs appear correctly. Now open developer tools  and find out which CSS classes are assigned by the tabs extension to the `<ul>`/`<li>`/`<div>` elements.

Assign these classes right in the base HTML. Done.

Answer (score 1):

Don't load all the content at once. The jQuery UI tabs have the capability of loading additional content by AJAX.

Alternative hide the content first, and display it by jQuery later.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Christian. The idea was no to use AJAX to load content, but to load it all at once. Otherwise your suggestion would work too.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
$(function() {
  $("#container-1").tabs();
});
```

Comment: Don't just post code as an answer. Try to give some explanation too.